# Numpy split data with delimiter at once

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a numpyarray, it looks like this:

```
[
[1,2,6,1,5]
[3,6,46]
[7,7,6,6,6,62,4]
[2,4,52,85,78]
]
```

the data is heterogeneous

My question is now if it possible is without doing it for every single row (means no "for loop") to split the data by a delimiter.

the results should look like (3d array)

```
[
[[1][2][6][1][5]]
[[3][6][46]]
[[7][7][6][6][6][62][4]]
[[2][4][52][85][78]]
]
```

Comment: Is it a performance thing that you want to avoid loop or just for the sake of it?

Comment: Yes of course. My array is very large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Here's one approach using a flattened list version of the input array and then simply splitting -

```
def extend_dims_objectarr(a):
    v = np.concatenate(a)[:,None].tolist()
    idx = np.r_[0,np.cumsum(list(map(len,a)))]
    return np.array([v[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx[:-1], idx[1:])])
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [81]: a
Out[81]: 
array([[1, 2, 6, 1, 5], [3, 6, 46], [7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 62, 4],
       [2, 4, 52, 85, 78]], dtype=object)

In [82]: extend_dims_objectarr(a)
Out[82]: 
array([[[1], [2], [6], [1], [5]], [[3], [6], [46]],
       [[7], [7], [6], [6], [6], [62], [4]], 
       [[2], [4], [52], [85], [78]]], dtype=object)
```

**Approach #2 :** If you are okay with an array of arrays as output, here's another using list-comprehension -

```
np.array([np.array(i)[:,None] for i in a])
```

To get array of list as output, simply append `.tolist()` : `np.array(i)[:,None].tolist()`.

**Runtime test**

```
In [108]: a = np.array([np.random.randint(0,9,(i)).tolist() \
                  for i in np.random.randint(2,9,(10000))])

# @Allen's soln
In [109]: %timeit np.r_[list(map(lambda x: np.asarray(x).reshape(-1,1),a))]
100 loops, best of 3: 15.2 ms per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [110]: %timeit np.array([np.array(i)[:,None] for i in a])
100 loops, best of 3: 9.94 ms per loop
```

Comment: I thought the OP wants to avoid using for loops.

Comment: @Allen I thought so too, until [`OP clarified`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069539/numpy-split-data-with-delimiter-at-once/44070652?noredirect=1#comment75164895_44069539) that they are looking for performance. I guess it's always worth to wait for OP to clarify their actual targets :)

Comment: It's good I figured out a few more ways to do the same thing anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**

```
a = np.asarray([
[1,2,6,1,5],
[3,6,46],
[7,7,6,6,6,62,4],
[2,4,52,85,78],
])
```

**Solution**

```
#put the array to a DataFrame and then reshape it to a 3D array.
import pandas as pd
a2 = pd.DataFrame(a).applymap(lambda x: np.asarray(x).reshape(-1,1)).values

print(a2)
Out[264]: 
array([[array([[1],
       [2],
       [6],
       [1],
       [5]])],
       [array([[ 3],
       [ 6],
       [46]])],
       [ array([[ 7],
       [ 7],
       [ 6],
       [ 6],
       [ 6],
       [62],
       [ 4]])],
       [array([[ 2],
       [ 4],
       [52],
       [85],
       [78]])]], dtype=object)
```

**Update**

Another approach without using pandas, with only numpy and built in functions.

```
a2 = np.r_[list(map(lambda x: np.asarray(x).reshape(-1,1),a))]

print(a2)

Out[312]: 
array([array([[1],
       [2],
       [6],
       [1],
       [5]]),
       array([[ 3],
       [ 6],
       [46]]),
       array([[ 7],
       [ 7],
       [ 6],
       [ 6],
       [ 6],
       [62],
       [ 4]]),
       array([[ 2],
       [ 4],
       [52],
       [85],
       [78]])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Isn't `applymap` essentially a loop hiding under the hoods?

Comment: Probably, but it's under the hood :-)

Comment: is it possible to do that without pandas? With only numpy